# Semantic UI Search Module disable default error messages

Tags: semantic-ui

Is there a way to disable the error messages from the search module in Semantic. I tried setting the error configuration as undefined like this:

```
$('search').search({
  error: undefined
});
```

But it did not work, can someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to disable it is just setting the error attribute at the configuration to false like this:

> $('search').search({ error: false });

Comment: Didn't you copy the same code you wrote first in your question?

Comment: yes sorry DanielM it was false instead of undefined i have edited my answer now thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, here is the approach to fully customize the message:

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    templates: {
     message: function(type, message) {
       html = '<div>some html</div>';
       return html;
     }
    }
  })
;
```